# What are the best "fresh" android development books

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android for 6 months and now I decided to read some fresh book. All that I read was an old book on russian based on android 2.3. It sucks, I know. 
So could you help me to make a right choise? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question belongs to "asking about outside resource"

"

Comment: Yes. I was learnig it just two months. ABC

Comment: I have flagged to close because this is not the sort of question that should be asked or answered on stack overflow as it is pointing to outside resources and is primarily opinion based. It's worth considering though whether or not you need to learn android specific things after six months or if it is your java/xml that needs more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know java pretty well, and have clear concepts about OOP. You can learn android from anywhere. But to have a smooth flow and step by step learning I would recommend [this Android Contest](http://www.codeproject.com/Competitions/757/Android-Tutorial-Contest.aspx) of [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/). It is a series of very nice and winning articles on specific topics of android. If you complete it, you'll definitely learn a lot.